# How to specify the language in which the results for a jax-ws service should be returned?

Tags: java, internationalization, jax-ws

I am currently working on a jax-ws webservice which is suppossed to provide internationalised  search results from a database.

I've looked over the internet for finding a concrete sample of code where the languageCode/languageId is sent in a standard manner along with the SOAP envelope (in order to avoid sending the languageId as a parameter of the webservice method), but haven't found anything concrete so far.

Can anyone recommend me a good approach on how to tackle this problem?

In the meantime i've found a manner to transport the metadata (languageId, user, password) over HTTP Request Headers 
javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/application-authentication-with-jax-ws/

Does anybody see some clear drawbacks in making use of such a transport method (over HTTP headers and not in the SOAP envelope)?

Comment: If you need a parameter, then why do you not like to having to pass it explicitly?

Comment: Username, password, languageId - i consider them meta-information for the method. I'd like to find a way to avoid having them within the parameters which are used by the method.

Comment: There is [WS-I18N SOAP extension](http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-i18n/#sec-soap-i18n). What jax-ws framework/engine do you use?

Comment: Then you need sessions.  You most likely do not want state in your webservice.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen in this case (and usually, too) i18n has nothing to do with state/sessions.

Comment: Metro Jax-WS is the framework i use.

Comment: @Vlad, if he needs to pass parameters at another time than at the actual call, you need to put them elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As also noted in another answer you can make use of standard [WS-I18N SOAP extension](http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-i18n/).

> SOAP documents that need to send international preferences SHOULD
>   include the i18n:international element information item in a header.
>   When sent from the requester to a provider, the header represents the
>   preferences of the requester or its client application. When sent in a
>   response message from the provider, the header represents the settings
>   that the service used to process the request.

Check how you can add SOAP headers in JAX-WS/Metro in this [blog post](http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/using_implicit_soap_headers_with) (it has links to specific steps details).

- [Adding JAX-WS handlers to web services and SOAP clients](http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/jaxws_handler_tutorial)
- [Using SOAPHandler for adding SOAP Header](http://devplace.wordpress.com/2007/09/24/adding-soap-header-in-java/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Not very surprisingly, but there is a standard for it. http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-i18n/

However I am not sure how viable it is.

Comment: can you point me to a concrete jax-ws sample code where it is made use of this?